# Is the win/loss credit bonus awarded to all players?

Tags: mechwarrior-online

Is the win/loss credit bonus awarded to all participants in a round, or only those connected (alive/spectating) at the end of the match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the players get the win/loss bonus based on their side's performance, you don't have to spectate the whole round.

However, if you are a new player and you die early, you might benefit by spectating your teammates and pickup some tips to improve your play.